# Vuepress link and script tags not working in dev mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuepress

I am facing some issue loading 3rd party script and stylesheets in [Vuepress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/). **It's not showing error** after adding it to head section of the front matter but I'm **not able to access** any of the `UIkit` class or make http calls. Newbie to Vue and Vuepress. Am I missing something?

```
head: [
    ['link', { rel: 'stylesheet', href: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/css/uikit.min.css` }],
    ['script',{ src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/js/uikit.min.js' }],
    ['script',{ src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/js/uikit-icons.min.js' }],
    ['script',{ src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1' }]
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to re-run the build command:
    npm run docs:dev